# tex4ebook: How to use dvisvgm_hashes properly?

Tags: tex4ht, tex4ebook

I tried to compile a tex file with a lot of math formulae. I tried

> tex4ebook -c test.cfg -f epub+dvisvgm_hashes test

with the test.tex

```latex
\documentclass{amsart}

\begin{document}
Two formulae displayed:
\[e^{i\pi}+1=0\]
and
\[\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{n^2}=\frac{\pi^2}6\]
let's see the effect.
\end{document}
```

the test.mk4

```lua
if mode == "draft" then
  Make:htlatex {}
else
  -- Make:add("biber","biber ${input}")
  Make:htlatex {}
  -- Make:biber {}
  Make:htlatex {}
  Make:htlatex {}
end

Make:tex4ht{}
Make:t4ht{}
```

The test.cfg

```latex
\Preamble{xhtml,pic-align}
 \Configure{Picture}{.svg}  
 \makeatletter
 \makeatother
 \DeclareRobustCommand{\[}{\begin{equation*}}
 \DeclareRobustCommand{\]}{\end{equation*}}
 \begin{document}
 \EndPreamble
```

where the extension dvisvgm is used to accelerate the production of svg images, and it complained

> ...texmf-dist/scripts/make4ht/extensions/dvisvgm_hashes.lua:251: attempt to concatenate field 't4ht_par' (a nil value)

I looked at dvisvgm_hashes.lua, and inserted the code

```lua
if v.params.t4ht_par == nil then
  v.params.t4ht_par = ""
end
```

into

```lua
for _,v in ipairs(make.build_seq) do
  if v.params.t4ht_par == nil then
    v.params.t4ht_par = ""
  end
  if v.name == "t4ht" then
    v.params.t4ht_par = v.params.t4ht_par .. " -p"
  end
end
```

Then I compiled and it complained a lot of not-found errors during `Copy: cp test###x.svg test-epub/OEBPS/ ...`
and the content.opf contains test###x.svg which does not exist. Seemingly it is due to an incompatibility of tex4ebook and dvisvgm_hashes. I look for a workaround.

Comment: could you please also add a TeX MWE?

Comment: @michal.h21 Added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems like a bug in the `dvisvgm_hashes` extension. The fixed version is available in the [make4ht](https://github.com/michal-h21/make4ht/blob/master/extensions/dvisvgm_hashes.lua) repository.

Quick fix without need to update the extension is to drop the `Make:t4ht {}` line from the build file. It isn't useful in your case anyway, because it is executed automatically by both `make4ht` and `tex4ebook`. You should include it in the build file only in the case if you wanted to pass some custom parameters.

This build file is the same as your original one, but it  doesn't suffer from the  error:

```
if mode == "draft" then
  Make:htlatex {}
else
  -- Make:add("biber","biber ${input}")
  Make:htlatex {}
  -- Make:biber {}
  Make:htlatex {}
  Make:htlatex {}
end
```

Comment: There are still warnings like `cp: cannot stat 'test0x.svg': No such file or directory` and the existence of `test0x.svg` in `content.opf`

Comment: @FrankScience ah I see. it should be fixed by the recent `make4ht` update